# delay OCUnit execution in device - xcode

Tags: unit-testing, ocunit

I am am able to run OCUnit in XCode 4 with the some sample code.

But, I would like to modify it so that the tests run a little later than at startup.

For example, I would like my splash screen to finish, and test after that.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I sounds more like you're doing a functional or integration test that a true unit test.

However there is a free too called [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) by GorillaLogic that might help you to achieve what you're after. At will allow you to run unit tests, etc. including delays based on the state of your UI.